# Changing ListBox value asynchronously

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm in a situation and I want to know that it is possible or not.

I want to change the Items of ListBox control depend on TextBox value.

Means when I change textbox value, the listitems of ListBox changes asynchronously (without pressing button or something).

Is it possible? If it is possible please guide me some references, tutorials or something.

Comment: Hook up `TextChanged` event and change your listbox value. you're done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely getting what you need,but i hope the cases below would help you;
**Case 1 : If you have a listbox with several items in it and you want the item to be selected that matches the text in textbox.** If this is the case the code below should do the job;

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.TextLength >= 1)
        {
            int index = listBox1.FindString(textBox1.Text);//Search any items that match Textbox's text.
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;//Highlight the match
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Add the code above to the TextChangedEvent of your textbox and make sure you rename the controls in the code with the ones you have.If this is not the case,see the below one;

**Case 2 : You have a textbox and you want to add the text of textbox to listbox**.On more thing i would like to tell you,the code below assumes that when you press the **Enter Key** while the textbox is focused,it's text(if any) should be added to listbox.Add the code below in KeyDownEvent of your textbox,and make sure to rename the controls.If this is the case the code below would help you;

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string item = textBox1.Text;
        if (textBox1.Text.Length >= 1)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)//If Enter key is pressed while textbox is focused.
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @AnkhbayarBayarsaikhan Please upvote the answer if it helped you so that others with the same problem could find a solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code will help you:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(TextBox1.Text == "One")
        listBox1.Items.Add("One");

    if(TextBox1.Text == "two")
        listBox1.Items.Add("two");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do that async. Just use the TextBox.TextChanged-Event.